# Need to add words in a Trie

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, java.util.scanner, trie

Can any one help me how to add word in a Trie really new to data structure

```
/**
 * This method adds a word to the Trie
 * 
 * @param s - word to add to the Trie
 * @param data - Data associated with word s
 */
public void addWord(String s, E data) {

}
```

Comment: Are you planning to create Trie data structure yourself ?

Comment: Show us what you done.

Comment: There is a Trie article in wikipedia - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#Algorithms in which you can find pseudo code for the insert operation.

Comment: @Kunal Yes and I need to use scanner to add words in there but i dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear what the purpose of `data` is; do you want to associate some information with each stored string? Basically, adding a new string would mean that you start at the root of the trie, then read `s` character-wise and traverse the arcs of the trie correspondingly as long as this is possible. If all characters of `s` are consumed in this process, you are done; if there is some suffix of `s` left, you have to add new nodes and arcs to accomodate for the suffix. In either case, you arrive at a node where you can store `data` if this is desired.